# oracle query: get max value with some conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table called service_t,it has a column effective_dt which is populated with unix timestamp. I need  find  all rows with max effective_dt but the effective_dt must be less than a given value. I have the following sql but I don’t think it’s efficient:

```
Select *
  from service_t t1
 where t1.effective_dt <= :given_value
   and t1.effective_dt = (select max(effective_dt)
                            from service_t t2
                           where t2.effective_dt <= :given_value
                             and t1.id = t2.id)
```

Is this efficient or any other good ways? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean efficient in terms of performance or just a better way to code this?

Comment: in terms performance and abetter way to code it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using analytic functions is probably more efficient:

```
Select * from (
  select t1.*, 
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by effective_dt desc) rn
  from service_t t1
 where t1.effective_dt <= :given_value)
where rn = 1
```